# Account page in profile is not reflecting actual reputation

Tags: discussion, profile-page, merge-accounts

In my profile, I am seeing only 1 rep for account 'meta'. But in Meta page is showing actual rep and badges. Is it issue from my merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing your [Meta Stack **Exchange** account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/261653/sivaa-nethaji) with [your account here on Meta Stack **Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3557336/sivaa-nethaji).

These are two **different** accounts.

Meta Stack Exchange is an entirely separate site, to discuss the Stack Exchange network as a whole. It is a separate account with its own reputation and badges. You have no activity there, and thus have yet to earn anything.

Meta Stack Overflow is a dedicated child meta site for Stack Overflow alone. Your reputation here is a copy of the reputation of [your account on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3557336/sivaa-nethaji), but you can earn badges separately here. Your [Autobiographer badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer?userid=3557336) is one such badge, separate from the [badges you earned on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3557336/sivaa-nethaji?tab=badges).

Comment: Thanks. What is difference between Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @SivaaNethaji: I already expanded to include an explanation about the purpose of the different sites.

Comment: Corrected the questions.

Comment: @SivaaNethaji: I do explain that too; *Meta Stack Exchange is an entirely separate site, to discuss the Stack Exchange network as a whole*. The site has an [about page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/about). I do hope you already know what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Thanks :)  I got confused with multiple sites :(